# Entity Framework context is incorrectly loaded

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

In the following code snippet I'm placing a brakpoint at the return of the select.

**In this case the breakpoint is being hit correctly**

```
                         context.campaigns
                         .Include("adgroups")
                         .Include("campaigntimeranges")
                         .ToList()
                         .Where(p=> p.LastUpdate < fromDate && 
                                    p.campaigntimeranges.OrderByDescending(q => q.EntryDate).FirstOrDefault().DateStart >= fromDate && 
                                    p.campaigntimeranges.OrderByDescending(q => q.EntryDate).FirstOrDefault().DateStart <= currentDate
                               )
                         .ToList().Select(x => { 
                             return x; //Breakpoint here
                         }).ToList();
```

**In that case the (.ToList() is removed) the breakpointis never hit**

```
                         context.campaigns
                         .Include("adgroups")
                         .Include("campaigntimeranges")
                         .Where(p=> p.LastUpdate < fromDate && 
                                    p.campaigntimeranges.OrderByDescending(q => q.EntryDate).FirstOrDefault().DateStart >= fromDate && 
                                    p.campaigntimeranges.OrderByDescending(q => q.EntryDate).FirstOrDefault().DateStart <= currentDate
                               )
                         .ToList().Select(x => { 
                             return x; //Breakpoint here
                         }).ToList();
```

I wish I could use the first, working example however anything after the .ToList() is not loaded into context so the first one results in a collection of all "campaigns".

Why is that and how can I fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Function lambda inside `Select` function is not called because (watch for it!) it's NOT executed in your application. Entity framework translates this expression into an SQL expression and then executes it within SQL server.

When you add call to `ToList` function, it forces EF to execute query and return a result. `ToList` as you know returns an `List<T>` and for that reason `Select` is executed within your application and you can break there using a breakpoint.

```
context.campaigns.Where(/*condition*/).Select(/*selector*/); // returns IQueryable<T>
// IQueryable is translated into a SQL statement

var campaigns = context.campaigns.Where(/*condition*/).ToList(); // Returns List<T>
campaign.Select(/*selector*/); // campaign is a List<T>, and Select is not not translated to SQL, but executed directly
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right but what I've written above was for me to test things.. The real issue is that although I can see the query is correct (indicated by the breakpoint being hit) the context is **not** populated with the results..

Comment: `Select` part of your query cannot be to blame that you are not getting a result. It should be used to select columns, and which rows are selected depends on `Where` part. To debug this, open SQL Server Profiler (there is link in SSMS Tools menu), start watching and execute your query. When you execute the query in .NET, you should see the SQL statement in profiler. Try to execute it manually in SSMS and debug there why you don't get any results.